# CSharpCodeProvider and resolution of dynamic assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, assemblies, code-generation

I have an application where I'm using CSharpCodeProvider to allow for integrated scripting via C# code.  The scripts can refer to dynamically emitted assemblies (these are created via IL Emit); to allow this reference, I save the dynamically generated assembly to a file on disk, then add this location to the CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies collection.

This works fine for the first compilation and execution of the script.  I have code that instantiates a class generated from the script, which has a constructor taking parameters, of which some are types from the dynamically emitted assembly.  It looks like this:

```
        var hostType = _compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetType("ExMod.Engine.ScriptHost");

        var parameters = new List<object>();
        parameters.Add(simulation);

        var extraParameters =
            simulation.Environment.Controllers.
            Select(c => c.GetPrecompiledContext()).
            Where(c => c != null);
        parameters.AddRange(extraParameters);

        _scriptHost = (ScriptHostBase)Activator.CreateInstance(hostType, parameters.ToArray());
```

The extraParameters expression is where the references to the external dynamically generated types get added.

The problem occurs when I attempt to compile and run the script a second time.  It only occurs if I've also re-emitted a new version of my IL Emit assembly.  The Exception occurs on the Activator.CreateInstance call and is:

`MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'ExMod.Engine.ScriptHost' not found.`

Observations:

1. I've confirmed via the Debugger that a constructor does exist with the correct parameters.
2. I've also confirmed (using the Make Object ID in the Debugger) that the issue is caused because the 'Controller' parameter in the constructor (referenced type from the dynamically emitted assembly) is referring to the original dynamic assembly, rather than the most recently emitted dynamic assembly, which is why the types don't match and the constructor does not resolve.
3. When I run the CSharpCodeProvider compiler and then try to run the script, it never calls my AppDomain AssemblyResolve event, which is where I have special logic to always resolve to the 'most recent' dynamic assembly.

My theory is that somehow the CSharpCodeProvider is resolving the 'earliest' dynamic assembly rather than the 'latest'. This occurs because they both have the same name and location.  The question: how do I get the CSharpCodeProvider to resolve to the latest version of the dynamic assembly?

I've considered changing the location for each dynamically emitted assembly, but I'd prefer not to create a bunch of copies on disk for each script iteration.

Comment: CompiledAssembly uses Assembly.Load() to load the assembly.  You really ought to consider using an AppDomain so you can unload these assemblies again.

Comment: @Hans, I agree, using an AppDomain is a better solution.  Right now I leak about 23MB every time I build a moderate-sized project (emitting new assemblies) and that's without even running any scripts.  I can mitigate some of this by caching assemblies if the source code doesn't change, but it would definitely be better to run the whole simulation in an AppDomain (possibly even an external hosting process.)  These issues might push it higher up the priority list.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I can resolve the issue by having the Emit code create a new build number for each build.  I just use this in the code that generates the AssemblyName:

```
        var name = new AssemblyName();
        name.Name = "AB-PLC";
        name.Version = new Version(0, 0, Interlocked.Increment(ref _buildNumber), 0);
```

_buildNumber above is a simple static int field.

This allows the CSharpCodeProvider to resolve the correct assembly, as now the FullName of the different builds no longer match.  I still only have a single copy of the assembly exported to disk (overwritten with each IL emit build.)

I'd still be curious to know if it's possible to allow the CSharpCodeProvider to resolve the correct assembly without changing its FullName, but this solution is sufficient for my purposes currently.